# Button disappears at runtime, visible in Eclipse design view

Tags: java, android, listview, button, adapter

My app is for reading news from one site.  The news parse from RSS feed and display as list of elements that include title and date.  The main layout is ListView, and the layout post_entry for messages (news) looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
             android:orientation="vertical"
         >

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" 
            android:id="@+id/post_title">
      </TextView>
      <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/post_pubDate">
      </TextView>


</LinearLayout>
```

One TextView for the title, and another is for date.

Adapter for this view looks like this:

```
public class PostAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostItem> {

    public ArrayList<PostItem> messages;
    public LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PostAdapter(Activity context, int resource,
            ArrayList<PostItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        messages = objects;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView titleView;
        public TextView pubDateView;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_entry, null, true);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.titleView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            holder.pubDateView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.post_pubDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.titleView.setText(messages.get(position).title);
        holder.pubDateView.setText(messages.get(position).date);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

I want to add the button for refresh in the main activity.

After in the main activity looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:text="Refresh" 
    android:onClick="Update"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In graphical mode in Eclipse I see the list of items and the button below it.

Everything seems ok, but when I run my app there is no button on the screen. I see just list of the news.

Do you know why can this be?  And how to add the button below the list?

Comment: Have you set the visibility modifier for the button?  If I remember correctly, you should be able to set it through java code .setVisibility(VISIBLE) and/or through the XML.  However, it has been a while since I've worked with Android.